# Combinations of variable length with fixed set

Tags: haskell, permutation, combinatorics

I have a set of possible colors defined like this:

```
data Peg = Red | Green | Blue | Yellow | Orange | Purple
         deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
colors = [Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Orange, Purple]
```

And code which is a combination of colors defined like this:

```
type Code = [Peg]
```

I want to be able to generate the list of all possible combinations of length `len` that can be made from the defined colors.

This is my original idea. I'm still learning so I'm not even sure if I have made some syntactic errors or constructs that are not supported.

```
allCodes :: Int -> [Code]
allCodes len = map (\p -> Code p) (permutations len)
    where
        permutations::Int->[Peg]
        permutations 0 = [[]]
        permutations n = [x:xs | x <- colors, xs <- permutations (n - 1)]
```

This doesn't compile, I'm getting the error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling HW02             ( HW02.hs, interpreted )

HW02.hs:59:27: Not in scope: data constructor `Code'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

`Code` works in other places where I used it so I'm not sure what's going on here. I know there are functions like `replicateM` that can solve this quite easily, but I'd like to use only what comes in `Prelude`.

Comment: I should proably rename `permutations` to `combinations` :D

Comment: `Code` is a type, but you're using it in `map (\p -> Code p)` as a data constructor.  Data constructors are essentially special functions that make values, like `Just`, `Left`, `(,)` (two-tuples), or in your case `Red`, `Green`, `Blue`, etc.  Other data constructors include `[]` and `:` for lists.  That is the source of your error here.  Keep in mind that `type Code = [Peg]` just means that `Code` is an alias for `[Peg]`, you don't construct values of that type directly, it's like how `"abc" :: [Char]` or `"abc" :: String`, since `String = [Char]`, they're completely interchangeable.

Comment: To drive the point home, you don't have `map (\s -> String s) (["a", "b", "c"] :: [[Char]])`, this wouldn't compile because `String` isn't a data constructor, and none is needed when you already have `[Char]`.

Comment: Smack on my head!! I have somehow forgot that I'm dealing with a type here. Thanks!

Comment: What you have are permutations, as far as I can tell.  You might only want combinations, which would not care about order in the list.

Comment: To get just the combinations, you'll need a more complex generator function, that weeds duplicates.  I have a thought about the algorithm (which would basically produce a sorted list of combinations), but I'm not sure about the implementation.

Comment: This produces neither permutations nor combinations. They're just independent dice rolls, basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bhelkir's comment to the question has diagnosed your error correctly, so I'll skip that.

The logic of your `allCodes` function is fundamentally sound (setting aside the permutations vs. combinations issue).  One thing that's worth pointing out is that the same effect can be achieved as a one-liner by using two functions in the `Prelude`:

```
allCodes :: Int -> [Code]
allCodes len = sequence (replicate len colors)
```

It's instructive to follow this down to the bottom of the stack.  First, the `replicate` function makes a list of a specified length, filling all positions with the same value:

```
replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]
replicate 0 _ = []
replicate n a | n > 0 = a : replicate (n-1) a
              | otherwise = error "replicate called with n < 0"
```

So `replicate 3 colors` produces a list of three elements, all of which are the `colors` list.

Now, the `sequence` function is a bit magical:

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
sequence [] = return []
sequence (ma:mas) =
    do a <- ma
       as <- sequence mas
       return (a:as)
```

When `m = []`, however, this is the same as:

```
sequence' :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
sequence' [] = [[]]
sequence' (ma:mas) = [(a:as) | a <- ma, as <- sequence mas]
```

So basically, the one-liner is the same idea as your solution but refactored into two reusable pieces.

Comment: (...and this pattern is useful/common enough that it is given a name in `Control.Monad`, specifically `replicateM`.)

Comment: @DanielWagner: D'oh!  Yes... [the definition is literally `replicateM n x = sequence (replicate n x)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Control-Monad.html#replicateM).